# Heroku PHP GrapheneDB Connection Issue

Tags: php, heroku, neo4j, graphenedb

cant seem to connect php to graphenedb...

my code as below. i used the sample code as provided in the documentation but no use.

```
<?php

// https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp
// in composer.json:
// {
//   "require": {
//     "everyman/neo4jphp": "dev-master"
//   }
// }
// require at the top of the script
require('vendor/autoload.php');

// ...

$grapheneUrl = parse_url(getenv('GRAPHENEDB_URL'));

//this line is the problem with heroku... it cant seem to detect the class.
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client($grapheneUrl['host'], $grapheneUrl['port']);
echo var_dump($client);

$client->getTransport()->setAuth($grapheneUrl['user'], $grapheneUrl['pass']);



//print_r($client->getServerInfo());
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Alberto, one of the founders of GrapheneDB. I'd like to help you sort out your connection issues.

Have you made sure you have installed Neo4jPHP correctly using composer?
You should run `$ composer update` after updating the `composer.json` file to update your dependencies.

Neo4jPHP is not currently not actively maintained so even if that works, I'd encourage you to use Neoxygen Neoclient instead. These are the necessary steps:

**Include the dependency in `composer.json`:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "neoxygen/neoclient": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

**Update your dependencies**

`$ composer update`

**Require the library and configure the connection:**

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

$url = parse_url(getenv('GRAPHENEDB_URL'));

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', $url['scheme'], $url['host'], $url['port'], true, $url['user'], $url['pass'])
    ->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
    ->build();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! yes it helps! using the neoxygen client instead of neo4jphp works.